# Como fazer uma DIV com um texto atravessado. Tipo um texto passando por dentro de uma DIV

Tags: html, css

Exite alguma forma de fazer um texto transpor uma `div`, tipo entrando de um lado e saindo do outro?

Minha ideia seria algo tipo essas imagens. Onde o texto começa de um lado e atravessa *por dentro* da `div`. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso com CSS, e que eu possa mudar o texto sem ter que mexer no código do CSS pra ficar adaptando cada vez que eu troco o texto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Não precisa ficar exatamente como nas imagens, é só para ilustrar a ideia.

Modelo de código:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.texto {
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    perspective: 120px;
}
.texto span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
    <span>meu texto</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Dá pra colocar o elemento `::before` com `z-index: -1` e o elemento `::after` com `z-index: 1`. Deixando o elemento "do meio" com `z-index: 0`. Ou esquecer CSS e partir pro SVG, que é bem mais simples de manipular.

Comment: Não sei nem se eu deveria comentar isso por ser off-topic, mas suas perguntas são excelentes!

Comment: @fernandosavio valeu jovem, boa parte delas são para enriquecer a comunidade tentando trazer mais conteúdo pro "data base", é uma maneira de manter as coisas movimentadas, manter o engajamento dos colaboradores etc. Obrigado pela gentileza =)

Comment: Dá pra fazer com SVG.

Comment: @Renan acredito que esse é um caminho sim! afinal um é ::before, e o outro é ::after, acho que daria para fazer trabalhando os z-index sim

Comment: @DiegoSouza sim SVG ajuda muito nessas horas, o clip-path tb resolveria, mas não funciona no IE :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brincando um pouco com o exemplo do @AndersonCarlosWoss e fazendo algumas modificações consegui um resultado que me parece "aceitável".

A única diferença é que criei um `::after` para sobrepor a borda da direita e modifiquei algumas unidades para se adaptar ao tamanho da fonte do elemento principal.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.teste {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.teste::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5em;
  top: -0.1em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border: 0.25em solid lightblue;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(-40deg);
}

.teste::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5em;
  top: -0.1em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border-right: 0.25em solid lightblue;
  transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">Open English</div>
<div class="teste" style="font-size: 13px;">Open English</div>
<div class="teste" style="font-size: 18px;">Open English</div>
```

Comment: Cara muito bom tb!

Comment: Muito boa a ideia de usar o tamanho da fonte nas medidas.

Answer (score 5):

> Esta forma reproduz a logo da Open English, mas não exatamente um texto passando por dentro do quadrado, carecendo de alterações¹ para tal.

Uma forma que chega bem próximo é aplicar o estilo no elemento `:before` (ou `:after`) do `span`, com perspectiva para dar o dimensionamento do elemento:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 82px;
  height: 67px;
  border-top: 8px solid lightblue;
  border-right: 7px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom: 8px solid lightblue;
  border-left: 10px solid lightblue;
  transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(-40deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span>open english</span>
```

Mas, desta forma, acabei ficando muito engessado, pois acabei definindo as medidas na mão e, assim, se o tamanho da fonte ou do próprio elemento variar, acabará quebrando o design.

---

1: Alterações estas que tentarei fazer em breve, mas deixo a resposta aqui até como incentivo a outras respostas.

Comment: Mas pelo que vi o quadrado azul fica num z-index menor né? Nesse caso se a borda direita coincidisse com o texto ficaria por trás do texto, correto?

Comment: @fernandosavio bem notado. Fiquei focado na logo da open english e esqueci deste detalhe.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito bom jovem, valei por contribuir e deixa o legado!

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma versão animada, inclusive fiz uns ajustes com `box-shadow`, e uma opção mais próxima do que era a logo da Open English.

A técnica tb é usando *pseudo-elementos* um com `z-index` `-1` e com `z-index` `2` assim um fica por cima e o outro por baixo do texto.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: rgb(248, 215, 255);
    height: 100%;
}

.texto {
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    perspective: 120px;
}
.texto span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: blueviolet;
    margin: 20px;
    animation: textox 5.5s linear infinite;
}
.texto::after, .texto::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: calc(100% - 36px);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-15deg);
}
.texto::after {
    
    border-left: 16px solid limegreen;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
}
.texto::before {
    border-top: 6px solid limegreen;
    border-bottom: 6px solid limegreen;
    border-right: 16px solid limegreen;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black, inset -5px 0px 5px -5px black;
}

@keyframes textox {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-200%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
    <span>meu texto</span>
</div>
```

**Segundo modelo**, agora mais similar ao logo da Open English:

Segue o código com a animação:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(gray, silver);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}

.texto {
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 33%;
    perspective: 120px;
}
.texto span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    animation: textox 6s linear infinite;
}
.texto::after, .texto::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: calc(100% - 36px);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-15deg);
}
.texto::after {
    height: 67%;
    width: 6px;
    left: calc(50% - 48px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 66%, blue 66%);
    z-index: -1;
}
.texto::before {
    border-top: 6px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 6px solid blue;
    border-right: 6px solid blue;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes textox {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-200%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
    <span>meu texto</span>
</div>
```